# javascript - list urls of every button with given text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a webpage with hundreds of download buttons. is there a way to use the chrome console to output the urls of every button that says 'download' to put into a batch downloader?

Comment: So write a script that selects the elements....

Comment: How are you passing the url?

Comment: Did you try anything from your end? Please post your code so we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

This code gets all the buttons from a page and if the button's text is '**download**' it will log the **href** attribute for that button.

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(e => {
        if(e.innerText === 'download') {
            console.log(e.getAttribute('href'))
        }
    })
```